# Number of prime divisors

Tags: summation, prime-numbers

Is there a way to express all the prime divisors of a natural number x as a function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The number of distinct prime divisors is a well-known arithmetic function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DistinctPrimeFactors.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel Hast points out with [this link to mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DistinctPrimeFactors.html), the function that inputs an integer $x$ and outputs the number of distinct prime divisors of $x$ is usually denoted $\omega(x)$.

You can write its definition in a variety of ways.
$$\begin{align*}
\omega(x)&=\sum_{\large\substack{p\,\mid\, x\\p\text{ prime}}}1\\\\
\omega(x)&=\#\{p\in\mathbb{N}:p\text{ is prime, and }p\mid x\}\\\\
&\text{etc.}
\end{align*}$$
However, it is just as valid and rigorous to write the definition simply as

> $\omega(x)$ is defined to be the number of distinct prime divisors of $x$.

This is also "expressing $\omega$ as a function".